# Updating view from asynchronous service

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am facing the following scenario:

My application contains a lot of information (stored in classes), the user can search the information for specific words (similar to the file search in Windows).

Once the user hit the search button, the search should begin asynchronously and collect results in the background. The search process can take a long time. Let's say the class which handles the searching is called SearchService (SearchService.cs).

The user can open a results view while the search service is working which contains a datagrid of results that is required to be updated as more results are found.

So basically:

Service is collecting information asynchronously -> View Model should get the already existing results and should be notified of new results -> View with datagrid should be updated asynchronously

How should I implement this? Let's say the View Model exposes an ObservableCollection to the view, but how should that collection be updated from the service?

I am using Prism and MEF.

Comment: I'm in the design stage so I haven't written anything yet, but I'm thinking maybe the View Model should read the existing results from the service while stopping it somehow until attaching a listener which will update the view model for each subsequent change. I'm just unsure on what is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Binding` object for the results, set this additional [IsAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync.aspx) property:

```
"{Binding PropertyName, IsAsync=True}"
```

Next, in your view model add a method like this:

```
public object RunOnUiThread(Delegate method)
{
    return Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, method);
}
```

Now you can create a callback handler delegate with whatever parameters suit your needs and call your service asynchronously like this:

```
Model.GetResultsAsync(GotResultsCallbackHandler);
```

The service can store a reference to the callback handler and call it whenever it has more results. In your view model again, you could get your results like this, making sure that you update the UI on the UI thread:

```
RunOnUiThread((Action)delegate
{
    ResultsCollection.AddRange(results);
});
```

This is kind of pseudo-code... please ask if you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reactive Extensions (Rx) to achieve this.

You service could expose a method which returns an `IObservable` of the collected result. Your service can then publish results on this `IObservable` as the results get collected by the service. And, your ViewModel can subscribe to this `IObservable` and update the `ObservableCollection` as and when the results arrive on `IObservable`

Pseudo code as below:

Service Class:

```
public class Service
{
    public IObservable<Result> GetResults()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(Service service)
    {
        service.GetResults().Subscribe(x => Results.Add(x));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

[Link to read about Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)